# sqlite3 user authentication bypassed by db browser

Tags: authentication, sqlite

I have followed the steps to add user authentication in sqlite3 database. 
When trying to access the tables from authenticated db, without the user name, gives me 'user not authenticated' error. That was what we wanted.

But now when i open the the db with db browser for sqlite3, it opens.
Why is it so?

Is there any way i can prevent my db from being accessed by anything else

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt) says:

> The `sqlite_user` table is inaccessible (unreadable and unwriteable) to
>   non-admin users and is read-only for admin users.  However, if the same
>   database file is opened by a version of SQLite that omits
>   the `-DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION` compile-time option, then the `sqlite_user`
>   table will be readable by anybody and writeable by anybody if
>   the "`PRAGMA writable_schema=ON`" statement is run first.

And a version of SQLite without the authentication checking code will not check the authentication.

To prevent anybody else from reading the database file, you must encrypt it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So encryption is the last resort.

Comment: Actually, as the minimum needed, it's the *first* resort.